# Limit Text to 2 lines using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to show a long html text limited to only 2 lines. The long text could contain line breaks (br).

**Example 1:**

### Input

Hello World.

### Output

Hello World.

**Example 2:**

### Input

<a>Hello World</a>. This is first line.<br>
This is the second line of the text which would span across multilple line. This is the second line of the text which would span across multilple line

### Output required

<a>Hello World</a>. This is first line.<br>
This is the second line of the text which would span across multilple line. This is the sec..

Could some one help me with a regex?

Comment: Why dont you put everything and then using CSS, have a fixed height and width with overflow:ellipsis

Comment: Follow this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730361/limit-number-of-lines-in-text-by-a-regular-expression

Comment: @Rajesh But I need to show a link something like "ReadMore" if the text is truncated. If I use CSS, I will not be able find whether the full text has fit into or it is truncated